ckan sharing same cookie in 2 different machine's browser
I am currently working on ckan version 2.10 and deployed to a docker.
I have 2 machine with google chrome installed and both machine visited the same ckan's website. Let's called it PC1's browser and PC2's browser.
I login to sysadmin in PC1's browser then I copied the ckan's cookie value from PC1's browser then I pasted the ckan's cookie value into PC2's browser cookie value then I refreshed PC2, PC2 is logged in the same username as PC1.
PC2 browser is shown as login (with the same username as PC1), even though I didn't login in PC2.
May I know how can I not allow PC2 to login the same as PC1, after having the same cookie value?

First of all. This is normal behavior. You shouldn't share your session cookie with anyone.
Sharing it is similar to sharing a user token. Imagine a browser as a tool that will talk to the server. It's the same as using curl. The server checks the request and sees the session. This is enough to treat you as a logged in user.
What I can suggest for you:
Use redis to store sessions. For this update your CKAN config like this:
beaker.session.type = ext:redis
beaker.session.url = redis://localhost:6379/0

In this case, you'll be able to find all the user's sessions by the key pattern.
1) "beaker_cache:a44e8211291246f1bb99cf32ed41981c:session"
2) "beaker_cache:b6aedadff1c04ce8b98454117b9b126a:session"
3) "beaker_cache:7162acdd95d7461cacee3c1e7abecd18:session"
4) "beaker_cache:fdf12b6a8827463886174f805d64ab8e:session"

You can write a custom extension to update the user profile page by adding and extra tab there. For example "Active session". Deserialize the KEY value from redis with Pickle
import pickle

pickle.loads(b"\x80\x04\x95\xa2\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00}\x94(\x8c\a_domain\x94N\x8c\x05_path\x94..b16944\x8c\x0b_csrf_token\x94\x8c(ba2bed84c5d58ff08f75615265c1a77fe2626a32\x94u.")

And you'll get something like this:
{'_domain': None,
 '_path': '/',
 '_creation_time': 1724244436.0910249,
 '_accessed_time': 1724244596.900393,
 '_remember_seconds': 63072.0,
 'last_active': datetime.datetime(2024, 8, 21, 12, 44, 50, 498599),
 '_fresh': False,
 '_user_id': '950b63b8-d798-42c7-b42f-adcc53f8d005',
 '_id': 'b4e251fe866515a675a56eb5f0b549040d7c0a5404e2334247f4d8a7824c4d2e664b91fb145fe09fa4de97f072567f681e7cbb1694d437caa7f45019191f006d',
 '_csrf_token': 'ba2bed84c5d58ff08f75615265c1a77fe2626a32'}

Using this approach, you'll be able to filter out all the sessions related to the specific user and list them on a custom profile page. You can add a button to terminate all sessions or a specific one.
I must say, that if someone has the same cookie session as you, he will be using your active session too. So you wouldn't know if someone is using it. But this mechanism will allow you to terminate all the sessions if you think, that your account has been compromised somehow.
How do I know if someone is using my account along with me?
You can write a custom code that will log all the activity for a user. For example, you can use IAuthenticator method. If the user is logged in, you'll have it in toolkit.current_user. You'll also have access to the flask request object.
Something automatic to keep your account safer
Invalidate all the previous sessions every time the user logs in. For this, use the login method of the IAuthenticator interface. If you're using redis you already know, that if you're going to delete a respective Redis key, the app won't recognize a user by the session in a cookie and he will be logged out.
In this case, you'll be able to use only one device to log in to your CKAN account. But the problem with sharing sessions will still exist... for this, you can go further.
What's next?
For example, modify the login method to return the access and refresh tokens and store them with AJAX in the user's local storage. The access token will have a short lifespan (10 mins) and the refresh token will have a long (30 days) or infinite lifespan.
The access token will be used with a JS script and sent to the server. If it's invalid the server will respond and ask the script to invalidate the access token using the refresh token.
The refresh token will be used only once to generate a new token pair.
Every time we invalidate the refresh token we store it for a user. The refresh token will be a JWT token that will store information, for example, a username.
Imagine the situation:

Your access token has been stolen. In this case, an intruder will have access for less than 10 minutes and won't be able to generate a new access token when it's expired. That's why it's a good idea to keep an access token lifespan short.
Both access and refresh tokens have been stolen. In this case, two users can access a portal at the same time. If you access the portal after the intruder invalidated the refresh token and you're using the outdated one, we're notifying both users (via Web UI or email, or whatever) and forcing them to log in again.

In both situations, the intruder will be logged out automatically.
The user knows the credentials and can use them to log in again and a new pair of tokens will be generated.
